# ng-websocket. Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, websocket

I'm having a problem with Web Socket. I use `ng-websocket` and when it all works great when I'm testing on my PC with the URL `ws://localhost:8080//connectToGame`. But then I published web-app on domain and got this error:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
ws://lotteryskins-net.1gb.ru/connectToGame
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? The server works on Apache.

Comment: Did you find any solution?